# How do I keep Azure DevOps from treating infos and warnings as errors in my pipeline?

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, mkdocs

I am working on an Azure DevOps pipeline created without YAML. In the pipeline, node.js and npm are used to build some web interfaces. mkdocs is used to build web documentation.
My problem is that Azure DevOps treats some infos and warnings as errors:

[image: 4 erros of information and warning statements]

While the build does not fail, it is marked as only partially successful. I prefer to have a clean build.

How do I keep Azure DevOps from treating infos and warnings as errors? Or is it some setting I have to configure on the side of mkdocs and npm?

Comment: can you share your pipeline?

Comment: Sharing your pipeline will help us answer your question, and a snip of the logs where these statements print would help too. My initial guess is that the tool is writing output using STDERR which the pipeline sees as failures. There is a setting per task to disable this behavior.

Comment: Hi Christian, any update for this issue? If my answer can't resolve this issue, could you please share your build definitions and content of your script so that we can check it directly for you.

Comment: Please excuse the tardiness of my reply. Sharing the pipeline is frowned upon because of company secrecy. I should have mentioned the company environment since it was apparently part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the company firewall prevented npm from making ssl connections because of missing certificates or something. I added

```
npm set strict-ssl false
```

to the build pipeline which -ironically- makes the connection less secure, but it makes all errors go away which I prefer to suppressing the errors/warnings/info.

I don't know if `Don't Fail on Standard Error` would even do anything since the build did not fail, it was `partially successful`. I prefer to have it checked in case a real error occurs.

After looking at it some more I am not exactly sure the highlighting and specification of errors is correct in the pipeline results. Why would an info output be marked as error anyway?

Answer (score 1):

1.For the Info which is treated as error, you can **uncheck** the `Fail on Standand Error` option and then add `2>&1 | Write-Host` to your `mkdocs` command, see PS [About Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7)
. You should run the command via `Powershell` task.

2.And for the error about `fsevents`, it seems to be [one issue starting from npm V.3.10.8](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14042). Use [Node.js Tool Installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/node-js?view=azure-devops) to install the latest NPM version and run the pipeline again. If the issue persists, you can try [joefiorini's](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14042#issuecomment-251683306) workaround:

Add this script to your `package.json` file.

```
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "*"
  },
```